# comparing values of range from different arrays

Tags: perl

i am trying to compare values of range from @arr3 with values of range from @arr4 but i am not getting the desired output. please suggest me the modifications in the following code to get the output as
3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15 (without repeating the values eg 5 and 10) and total matched=11

```
my @arr3=(1..5,5..10,10..15); 
my @arr4=(3..7,9..12,14..17);

foreach my $line1 (@arr4) {
    my ($from1,$to1)=split/\.\./,$line1;

foreach my $line2 (@arr3) {

    my ($from2,$to2)=split/\.\./,$line2;

    for (my $i=$from1;$i=$to1 ;$i++) {
        for (my $j=$from2;$j=$to2 ;$j++) {
            if ($i==$j) {

                print "$i";print "\n";
            }   
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `for` loops like this

```
for (my $i = $from1; $i = $to1; $i++) { ... }
```

are incorrect, because the second clause `$i = $to1` should be a *test* to determine whether the loop should continue, whereas you are *assigning* the value of `$to1` to `$i` so the loop will never end if `$to1` is true. I imagine your tests have failed to complete?

I also think you are misunderstanding the way the *range operator* `..` works. An expression like `2..5` returns a *list* consisting of all the values from 2 up to 5, and is identical to `(2, 3, 4, 5)`.

So your array initialisation

```
my @arr3 = (1..5, 5..10, 10..15)
```

is the same as

```
my @arr3 = (
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
  5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
)
```

and so there is no need to use `split` on the array values as they have already been expanded for you, and the reason the values 5 and 10 are appearing twice in your output is because they also exist twice in the input.

If you want to find all unique values that are in *both* arrays, and you can rely on the values in `@arr4` being unique (i.e. there is no overlap like there is in `@arr3`) then you can write something like the code below. But if *both* arrays could have overlaps then you have to explicitly remove duplicates, and a solution using a hash which does this has already been posted.

This solution uses a *label* `V4` so that the `next` can go to the next iteration of the *outer* loop. Without it the rest of `@arr3` would be scanned for matches even after one had been found.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr3 = (1..5, 5..10, 10..15);
my @arr4 = (3..7, 9..12, 14..17);

V4:
for my $v4 (@arr4) {

  for my $v3 (@arr3) {

    if ($v3 == $v4) {
      print "$v3\n";
      next V4;
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
3
4
5
6
7
9
10
11
12
14
15
```

Comment: i understand the working of range operator. i tried to do the same as u suggested. but my data is stored in a file, i stored the data into an array from file using FH. then the range operator didnt worked. after simply printing the array it gave the output as 1..5, 5..10, 10..15 instead 1,2,3,4,5....15. that why i thought to use split. please suggest to get rid of this problem, i have already posted related problems but didnt got the proper solution. @Borodin

Comment: @user3867469: Please show the contents of your file

Comment: this is file1 having 2 columns                                        1..5   4.5
5..10   3.6
10..15   1.2
                                                                 this is file2                                                     3..7
9..12
14..17
so i want to print those numbers from file 1 which lie in file 2 and also having the value greater than 2.0 (2nd column from file1) and then counting those total no. @Borodin

Comment: please let me know if any more clarity required regarding the question.if u could provide me your email id, i can send my files. i had also modified my above code. for (my $i=$from1;$i<=$to1 ;$i++) { for (my $j=$from2;$j<=$to2 ;$j++) {...}} its giving the desired result but with repeated values (overlaping range) which i dont need.@Borodin

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash:

```
my @arr3 = (1..5, 5..10, 10..15); 
my @arr4=(3..7, 9..12, 14..17);

my (%nums1, %nums2);

$nums1{$_} = 1 foreach(@arr3);
$nums2{$_} = 1 foreach(@arr4);

foreach (sort { abs $a <=> abs $b} keys %nums1){
    print "$_\n" if exists $nums2{$_} 
}
```